# Configure Eclipse GIT (eGit) to Team foundation server

Tags: eclipse, git, tfs

Anybody know how to connect eclipse to tfs express via GIT, or even if it is possible?

The only help link I have seen in [tfs express was this one](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-git-eclipse).

But that one looks to be more aimed at the online version of tfs instead of express.

Comment: Have you tried to execute these steps against your on-premises install? it's true that Visual Studio Team Services is ahead feature wise compared with a local TFS installation but Git support is already available for quite some time on-premises. The steps are equal to connect to both VSTS and TFS.

Comment: Yes I did, Eclipse just cant connect to tfs or says the username / password is incorrect. I tried git via a command line app using the same details and it connected fine. Just eclipse is having issue

Comment: For this, did you already enabled the alternate credential as mentioned in the above link?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's supported. The TFS express is the free version of standard TFS. [Here is the detailed introduction.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx)

From OP:

The problem was, needed to:
Enable basic authentication on "team foundation server\TFS" in IIS

Comment: I was going down the git route in tfs as will also be connecting to XCode.

Comment: Has anyone got tfs express to work with eclipse via git?

Comment: The sure thing is that must be worked on the normal TFS server.Generally , it should also be valid on express version. Please try the method in this video https://vimeo.com/73386728

Comment: Please also note the security.  `Basic authentication is essentially sending the password as plaintext. By default, Team Foundation Server uses the Windows Challenge/Response (NTLM) authentication protocol.` Did you use another account different with your windows logon account    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833874(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect tfs to eclipse via git. In order to do this you need to install an eclipse plugin - `egit`.
Recent versions of `Eclipse` come with the `EGit` plugin already installed. However if your version doesn't have it already, you can easily install it. These are steps to install the plugin

1. Click on `Help` In the menu bar.
2. Select `MarketPlace`
3. In the searchbox type `EGit`
4. click the `Install` button